# kafka-console-producer read from file fails

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using kafka 11 and trying to write to a topic from a file.

I am using the command below

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list my-bootstrap-url:9092 --topic my.test.messages < my_file.txt
```

and it returns

```
ERROR Error when sending message to topic my.test.messages with key: 
null, value: 2376 bytes with error: 
(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 22 
record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers 
for my.test.messages-0
```

If I write message on the console it seems to work fine but trying to write from a file fails. So I am guessing its because i am piping the message.

Any insights on this?

Comment: that's strange - in Kafka 0.9/0.10 `kafka-console-producer` worked just fine. It looks like something strange with your cluster, so it takes too much time to retrieve metadata about cluster when sending a batch. When you're entering data manually, it looks it gets metadata before sending data

Answer (score 3):

Check out [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat), which explicitly supports streaming from `stdin`, per the example given in the doc:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog | kafkacat -b mybroker -t syslog -z snappy
```